# javascript code to download the whole page and email the link to the downloaded page

Tags: javascript, html

i was just wondering if there is any available code/function in javascipt that can download the html page and send an email link for the downloaded page.

All i am trying to do is to fill a form (with many fields and lots of text) on a page and when an user pushes the submit button : two things should happen
1) save the page with form as filled by the user 2)send a link to the file location. Please advise if approach is correct or let me know if there are other better ways.

thanks in advance

Comment: You would need server-side code to store the file and send the email, along with authentication to protect said files from unauthorized access. But, yes, it could theoretically be done completely in javascript (node.js).

Comment: plz can you point me to an example ?

Comment: Google forms will save the responses to a web form in a spreadsheet for you, in Google drive.  The spreadsheet containing the responses can be shared with associates like any other Google Drive file.  No JS needed.

Comment: The web page that I have developed will be used just over an intranet.  Using google services may complicate things. thanks for the input .

Comment: Downloading the HTML will not save the values set on the form, only the empty form. How about you just submit the form normally, save the values and create a new page, where user can see the submitted form with the saved values & send a link to that page instead?

Comment: That might just solve my problem. I am bit new to web development plz can you suggest me or plz point to one example how to submit, save and create new page ? thanks